# Firefox is not getting response from REST service if the request body goes beyond 13kb(kilobytes)

Tags: angularjs, firefox

We have a REST service which is running on the same server domain(example: https://qa1.com) as my client code(Angular1.4). No cross domain issues. All the request headers are set. This service works in Chrome and IE. In Firefox , it works if the request body is less than 13kb. If request body goes beyond 13kb, we are not getting any response(no error) from the server. We are using IBM Http web server and Websphere server.I have checked the parameter postSizelimit which is set -1. The same firefox works in other environments(https://Qa2.com) even if we send more than 13kb of data. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Issue with cipher suite configuration in the load balancer server.The correct cipher suite to support latest firefox is TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA. In our server , we have configured with TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA as the preferred cipher suite which is causing the issue. We replaced with latest cipher suite , the issue is resolved. A cipher suite is a set of cryptographic algorithms used for the following:

Protect information required to create shared keys (key exchange)
Encrypt messages exchanged between clients and servers (bulk encryption)
Generate message hashes and signatures to ensure the integrity of a message (message authentication)
A cipher suite specifies one algorithm for each of these tasks. For example, the RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 cipher suite uses RSA for key exchange, RC4 with a 128-bit key for bulk encryption, and MD5 for message authentication. Please refer to this link  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19728-01/820-2550/cipher_suites.html for more information